# Disable radio button while processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have radio buttons like this -

```
<input type="radio" class="radiofilter" name="btype" id="btype1" checked='checked' autocomplete="off"><label for="btype1">All</label>
<input type="radio" class="radiofilter" name="btype" id="btype2" autocomplete="off"><label for="btype2">Option 1</label>
<input type="radio" class="radiofilter" name="btype" id="btype3" autocomplete="off" ><label for="btype3">Option 2</label>
```

I have an event listener which fires a script once the radio button selection is changed -

```
$('input.radiofilter:radio').change(
                        function(){
                               if($('#btype1').is(':checked')) {
                                 z=1;
                               } else if($('#btype2').is(':checked')) {
                                 z=2;
                               } else if($('#btype3').is(':checked')) {
                                 z=3;
                               }
                               process(z);
                        });
```

Function process() takes a couple of seconds to process and the selection of radio button changes once the process is finished (after couple of seconds) leaving the user in doubt if the click on radio button has changed anything or not.

What I want to do is show a spinner overlay as soon as user clicks and hide the overlay once the process is finished

I thought this should be easy and did the following -

```
$('input.radiofilter:radio').change(
                        function(){
                               if($('#btype1').is(':checked')) {
                                 z=1;
                               } else if($('#btype2').is(':checked')) {
                                 z=2;
                               } else if($('#btype3').is(':checked')) {
                                 z=3;
                               }
                               $(".radiofilter").attr('disabled',true);
                               $("#loader").show();
                               process(z);
                               $("#loader").hide();
                               $(".radiofilter").attr('disabled',false);
                        });
```

adding .show() and .hide() before and after calling process()

But it doesn't work for some reason I can't understand. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Where is `#loader`? `.attr()` is incorrect for setting properties, use `.prop('disabled', true/false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "click" event, and you could do simpler:

```
jQuery('input.radiofilter').on('click', function(){
    if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){
        z = jQuery(this).prop('id').replace('btype',''); // if doesnt work try just changing prop to attr (it depends on the jQuery version you are using)
    }
    $("#loader").show();
    process(z);
    // this one have to be added on the end of the proccess function as a callback$("#loader").hide();
});
```

Hope that can help you, if need more help with this code just ask or send a message.

Comment: That's a smart way to do this, but I am not sure about callback. Can you explain how to add callback on process? Right now process is something like this -  function process(z){ //something }

Comment: Just put at the bottom of the function the hide(), because it will be the last code run (unlles you have an ajax call than you have to put on the ajax callback function "success"), thats the concept of callback.